How to retain original foreign key names from database in EF Core scaffolding?
I'm developing a new application using .NET Core 8, and it needs to work with a database containing more than 300 tables. I'm using EF Core to scaffold my context and entity classes from the database. However, I'm facing an issue with the naming of navigation properties for foreign keys.
When I scaffold the models, some of the generated navigation properties have strange names that don't match the actual foreign key names in the database. For example:
public virtual ICollection<Rpr_RepairRequest> Rpr_RepairRequestInspectionPersonel_FKNavigation { get; set; } = new List<Rpr_RepairRequest>();

In the database, the actual foreign key name is FK_Rpr_RepairRequest_HRM_Personel_InspectionPersonel_FK.
I've tried using the -UseDatabaseNames option with Scaffold-DbContext, but it only affects table and column names, not the foreign key names.
Here is what I've tried:

Running the scaffold command:

Scaffold-DbContext "Your_Connection_String" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models -UseDatabaseNames


Manually configuring the model in OnModelCreating:

public class YourDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Rpr_RepairRequest> Rpr_RepairRequests { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Personel> Personels { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Rpr_RepairRequest>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(e => e.Id);

            entity.HasOne(e => e.InspectionPersonel)
                    .WithMany(p => p.RepairRequests)
                    .HasForeignKey(e => e.InspectionPersonelId)
                    .HasConstraintName("FK_Rpr_RepairRequest_HRM_Personel_InspectionPersonel_FK");
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<Personel>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(e => e.Id);
        });
    }
}

However, manually configuring each foreign key is not feasible due to the large number of tables.
My question is:
Is there a way to make EF Core scaffold the navigation properties using the actual foreign key names from the database without manually configuring each one? If not, is there a more efficient way to handle this scenario?
Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Running the scaffold command:

Scaffold-DbContext "Your_Connection_String" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models -UseDatabaseNames

I expected this command to use the actual database names for tables, columns, and foreign keys, but it only applied to tables and columns.
2Manually configuring the model in OnModelCreating:
public class YourDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Rpr_RepairRequest> Rpr_RepairRequests { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Personel> Personels { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Rpr_RepairRequest>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(e => e.Id);

            entity.HasOne(e => e.InspectionPersonel)
                  .WithMany(p => p.RepairRequests)
                  .HasForeignKey(e => e.InspectionPersonelId)
                  .HasConstraintName("FK_Rpr_RepairRequest_HRM_Personel_InspectionPersonel_FK");
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<Personel>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(e => e.Id);
        });
    }
}


While this approach works, it is not feasible to manually configure each foreign key due to the large number of tables.

I suspect it's not supported but I've not really had much dealings with it. If you can't find anything, a workaround might be to dump the constraints from the database and generate the code from that. e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18622200/how-do-i-get-constraints-on-a-sql-server-table-column

EF Core Power Tools has an option to use the "older" method for navigation naming, could generate better names for you perhaps?

To make more specialized code and alternative coding styles, you can refer to these official tutorials: Customize the entity types, Advanced usage.

I don't know if it will make it more readable if you use attributes instead of model oncreating
public int MyWierdId { get; set; }
[ForeignKey("MyWierdId")]
public MyClass MyClass { get; set; }

so you just decorate your dto classes.
